# Doing logic inside command line

Tags: c, command-line, configuration, compilation, terminal

I'm fixing an bug in a Microcontroller compiler, so that one preference can be correcly selected...

I'm not going to detail it, but the thing is:

I have one file (Let's say, `create_code.txt`), and inside it I can use some special strings such as `{name.of.configuration}`, that it will be replaced with the correct configuration.

The problem is, that my configuration is a boolean, and I receive it as `true` or `false`, but I need to change this, to: `nothing` in case of `false`, or, `-x` in case of `true`.

In `C` it would be like this: `({my.config}?"-v":""))`. But what about putting something like this, inside a command line?

**EDIT:**

This is the "txt" file. `{upload.verify}` is the boolean that should be changed to `-v` or ``

```
tools.bossac.upload.pattern="{path}/{cmd}" {upload.verbose} --port={serial.port.file} -U {upload.native_usb} -e -w -v={upload.verify} -b "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin" -R
```

Comment: Frankly, "commandline" is not precise enough. Unix shell are generally Turing complete and can certainly do this. Do you have `/bin/sh`,`/bin/bash`, or some other unix shell available?

Comment: @dmckee Here is the final compiling code: `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/bossac --port=tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync -U false -e -w (true?"-v":"-xx") -b /var/folders/[.....].tmp/sketch_jul23a.cpp.bin -R`

Comment: You say 'it must work on Mac, Linux, Windows'...are you writing your own shell to handle this?  If not, while Mac/Linux is easy (relatively), writing code that will work on Windows without support like [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) is going to be very hard.  It is not clear what language supports the `tools.bossac.upload.pattern` variable names; it isn't `bash` in a default configuration.

Comment: Those {x.y} are "replaced" by the real value..